# SharePoint Migration Tool: Migrated files to OneDrive, but files not visible in OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

I've migrated files from an On-Premises Server to Users OneDrives, using SharePoint Migration Tool.

Logfiles shows migration has completed successfully.

But the user cannot see the files when logging onto OneDrive.

When I call the FULL PATH of the folder the files has been migrated migrated to (Documents - SharePoint Migration Tool requires me to specify a Destination Folder), I can see all migrated files, but the Documents folder is not visible in the Users OneDrive.

In other words, they have to know the URL of the folder I've migrated to.

Why is the Folder I've migrated everything to, not visible in the Users OneDrive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Even though everything in OneDrive was in English, OneDrive was actually running in Danish, so the parameter for the folder to upload to should have been "Dokumenter" and not "Documents".